# How can I echo the label of a salesforce custom object on a visualforce page?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, custom-object

I want to access the metadata of a custom object and display the name of the custom object.  This has been changed from the original and I want my page to always display the name without having to change any code or markup.

A label can be accessed as {!$Label.MyLabel}.

Is there something akin to {!$MyCustomObject.Label}?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this via the Global Variable $ObjectType i.e.

{!$ObjectType.CustomObjectName__c.Label}

also for these types of questions try the salesforce Beta, salesforce.stackexchange.com